# Did this character die in the 2017 Wonder Woman movie?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

If you've not yet seen the 2017 *Wonder Woman* movie. Please leave this page as it will reveal a major plot point.

> I'm referring to Steve Trevor's self-sacrificing efforts which result in a major explosion in which we assume Steve died piloting the plane but where the actual explosion is obscured by cloud and hidden from view.

Is there any evidence that I missed that would conclude that this character is;

- A. definitely dead
- B. definitely alive
- C. presumed dead by the viewer
  and other characters but with an option for film makers to reveal his
  miraculous survival in a sequel.

Comment: It's a "comic book".  Death means nothing (except for Spiderman's Uncle Ben).

Comment: And Batman's parents

Comment: Related: [Were there any other options for taking out the plane?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161103/21267)

Comment: Obviously, Scotty beamed him up during the explosion. Can't you see who this character really is? He actually brought a virgin goddess to bed and later showed her that he is no longer alive to become free again. Obviously, he was there to catch whales and while Scotty was busy building Transparent Aluminum, he ran this Wonder Woman scandal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## C.

The relationship between Wonder Woman and Steve Trevor has had several iterations in the comics, so let's go through your three options.

**A: he's definitely dead.** There is no canon reason to think this.  The death of Steve Trevor has never been an "accepted" part of Wonder Woman's story (unlike, say, Spider-Man with the death of Uncle Ben, or Batman with the deaths of his parents).

**B: he's definitely alive.** There is no canon reason to think he's currently alive. The airplane explosion has never been shown before (to the best of my knowledge), so there is no precedent for him coming back from it.

This leaves **C: he's presumed dead, but will probably come back.**  There is some precedent for this: In the *Justice League* three-episode arc "The Savage Time," the League goes back in time to stop Vandal Savage's machinations and Steve Trevor winds up rescued from a mission that would have otherwise killed him.  Diana and a much older Steve reconnect after the League returns to the present time.

Since *Justice League* (2017) will feature the Flash, it's possible they'll do something similar and use speed-force-time-travel shenanigans to bring Steve back into the fold.

Comment: Steve Trevor is the Winter Soldier.

Comment: ...and there's precedent for Flash time travelling in BvS - good call @PlutoThePlanet

Comment: You're saying C like he'll definitely survive. He might survive, we don't know. Although as of the knowledge of WW, he went KABOOM

Comment: @Edlothiad: Please reread the OP. "C" does not mean what you've somehow decided it means.

Comment: Hmm I see. But that C is silly because it just removes the validity of A and probably B making the options pointless?

Comment: @Edlothiad I don't think so.  OP was asking if there's some canon reason to think that (A) he's definitely dead, meaning this is how he dies in the comics; (B) he's definitely alive, meaning this happens in the comics *and then he comes back*; or (C) neither of those but he might come back. It isn't A or B because this particular event never happened in the comics, so that leaves C.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet this question is most definitely **not** asking about the comics, but instead purely about the films.

Answer (score 13):

Well I mean without going to any form of "official/unofficial" sources, Yes.

He was on a plane with a load of gas that would kill him, 17000+ feet up (5000+ metres), without a parachute and either land or water below him, either way from that height they're effectively the same.

The explosion from the plane alone looked big enough to decimate him. Followed by the impact from 17000 feet of free-fall. He's dead.

Now on to the novelisation. This is as canon as you want it to be. But here it goes.

> With numbed fingers he **took his pistol from its holster and pointed it at the bombs**. He chuckled to himself. He wasn’t afraid. But he was wistful. He wanted to show Diana the beautiful parts of this world. To share it with her. Newspapers and breakfasts. It was not to be.
>   It was not to be.
>   Still, he couldn’t stop smiling when he thought of her, and of what he was doing, and what this would mean for the world: Peace.
>   The world was going gray. He was getting loopy. He closed his eyes and pulled the trigger and as he did he said…

This seems to suggest he shot at bombs, igniting and killing him most likely. The way he acted seems to suggest that he was about to die.

> She exploded, a half-God **bent on vengeance**, and in one savage push, she freed herself from the tire tread wrapped around her.

[..]

> Then the image of Steve’s face filled her mind. **Their last moment together...**

This seems to further suggest he's dead and gone forever.

RIP Steve <s>Rogers</s> Trevor

That being said, it's a comic book film, they'll bring back whoever they want.

Comment: Thanks @Edlothiad - I didn't know there was definitely no parachute and  didn't know about the book detailing him shooting the bombs.

Comment: Ah well parachute-wise that's off memory, I don't think he was wearing one.

Comment: 17000 feet of free fall isn't a death sentence. It's actually quite survivable and there are several real world examples. E.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Alkemade

Comment: Lets just say the odds of survival are INCREDIBLY f*ing slim.

Comment: If you go by examples of survival, there aren't many things that are a death sentence.

Comment: I don't think Steve was above a forest of snow-covered Pine Trees. Besides, if he did survive, he'd have gone and found Diana.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I can't speak for the explosion part, but free fall survivors are actually relatively common. As long as you can work yourself into the right posture and aim towards something relatively forgiving (skylights, trees, snow, etc.) your odds of survival are pretty good.

Comment: There was like 2 listed there that fit the category. I imagine a lot more people fall out of planes and died

Comment: This is comic books. Anyone can survive any arbitrary level of danger as the plot demands. For all we know he was teleported out or fell through a random dimensional rift into another part of the multiverse at the last second. You can't assume anything without a body. Heck, *even then* it's a clone or fake half the time. And hey, this is Wonder Woman, so maybe she can snag him out of Hades.

Comment: Saying "this is comic books" is terrible basis for an answer. Because really this is a film, meant for the masses, most of which aren't going to just take random explanations of survival. Unless the DCEU wants to return to the shambles it was before.

Comment: @Edlothiad It's a terrible basis for an answer. It's a great basis for pooh-poohing an answer that tries to apply logic to argue that someone is dead. lol